# Get the Workflow Status for InfoPath Form Open Rule

Tags: workflow, infopath

I need to get the Workflow Status on an InfoPath form library in the InfoPath form.  For instance, I want to place a rule on the form open that checks to see if the workflow is not "Completed" and set the view to ReadOnly ( I think its a value of 5). But after upgrading to SP2010, I cannot see the Workflow name in the Data Connection of the list.  I worked fine in SP2007, so there must be a new method to obtain this.  Can anyone guide me?

Bismarck